# Apache mod_rewrite fall-through only after a login?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have mod_rewrite active with the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(uploads|dist|doc|includes/languages)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|mp3|wav)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Every call, except calls to a few public folders, gets redirected to index.php where I initialize my PHP application.

I generate documentation with phpDocumentor. All the documentation goes into `{root dir}/doc`. Every page in this documentation has its own `*.html`. Access is thus only possible if you access the `.html` file directly
By excluding the `doc` directory in the .htaccess, I can access the content, but so can everyone else.

What I want to do is using the login of the main app and only allow certain logged in people to read my documentation.

Is this possible using some Apache setting, editing the .htaccess file, or maybe using a clever PHP trick?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention: I cannot edit the documentation generated.
These files get automatically updated every 15 minutes.
I cannot add any code to these files...

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect users that aren't logged in by adding something to the header of those documentation pages like

```
if (!$loggedIn) {
    header('Location: /');
}
```

where `$loggedIn` is whatever conditional you have for whether a user is logged in or not.

Comment: I guess you mean I add this code to the top of each generated HTML page? I cannot do that, see my edit why..